# form_for with module and namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-form-for

I have the follow models in Finance module:

```
class Finance::BillRec < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :bill_rec_offs, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end

class Finance::BillRecOff < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :bill_rec
  ...
end
```

I'm doing this on my form_for:

```
<%= form_for([@bill_rec, @bill_rec_off]) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :finance do
  resources :bill_recs do
    resources :bill_rec_offs
  end
end
```

And the error:

```
undefined method `finance_bill_rec_finance_bill_rec_offs_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000070757e0>:0x0000000708bec8>
```

However, the route finance_bill_rec_bill_rec_off_path(@bill_rec_off) works well.

How can I do on a form_for with namespace and nested routes with module?

Comment: It looks like you posted the same question on google groups. Add a link to it here so if it's answered there, people here can be notified.

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4404430

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
form_for([:finance, @bill_rec, @bill_rec_off])
```

or if it doesnt help

```
form_for([@bill_rec, @bill_rec_off], url: finance_bill_rec_bill_rec_offs_path(@bill_rec, @bill_rec_off))
```

Comment: Don't work. ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `bill_rec_bill_rec_offs_path' for #<#<Class:0xb115afc>:0xb119d3c>)

Comment: Hmm are you sure you have your instance variables set correctly? And each variable is an instance from the respective class? (asking because their names are very similar)

Comment: Yes. It was working, but now I needed to separate in modules because the number of files is increasing.

Comment: Hey!! rrsrs.. we forgot the **finance_** in the beginning of the route...

form_for([@bill_rec, @bill_rec_off], url: finance_bill_rec_bill_rec_offs_path(@bill_rec, @bill_rec_off))

It's working well, thanks!!

Comment: Nice! Updated my answer too :)